# Can I change the border color in Apps I write in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, border, windows-10

I have noticed that the border color of desktop applications I create in Windows 10 is an awful White. There is no Red surrounding the X in the close button. However the same application in Visual Studio is the traditional Blue and the Close button is Red. Why does it change in the Run mode? Is there any way to change the color?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 is very flat in this issue. I don't know if I understand your question, but this can be helpful.

https://techjourney.net/enable-color-window-title-bars-in-windows-10/

Maybe put more informations. Thanx!

Comment: What I mean is that if I were to create a Windows Form program in Windows 7, the border around the window is a blue color and the exit button has a red background. In Windows 10 that same app, the minimize, maximize, exit buttons have no background color at all. The appearance of my app changed when I installed Windows 10. Is there a setting that controls the appearance of those buttons on top?